# computing inverses in truncated polynomial rings manually for NTRU encryption

Tags: ntru, arithmetic, pen-and-paper

Can someone explain how to find inverses in truncated polynomial rings manually (i.e. on pen and paper)?
As an example from the tutorial:

> Example. Take $N=7$, $q=11$, $a=3+2X^2-3X^4+X^6$. The inverse of $a \bmod 11$ is
>   $a^{-1}=-2+4X+2X^2+4X^3-4X^4+2X^5-2X^6$, since
>
> $(3+2X^2-3X^4+X^6)*(-2+4^X+2X^2+4X^3-4X^4+2X^5-2X^6) \equiv -10+22X+22X^3-22X^6 \equiv 1 \mod 11$.

How to find $a^{-1} = -2+4X+2X^2+4X^3-4X^4+2X^5-2X^6$, manually, not using the pseudocode?

Comment: I don't get your "not pseudo-code". To do it manually, you should execute the pseudo-code manually.

Comment: I want to know all step of the process, so i can solve it with handwriting, if its posible

Comment: idon't understand the code on the Techncl report

Comment: To be honest, there is typically a fair amount of work required to do this by hand even for such a small example. It requires long division of polynomials as you are basically doing the extended euclidean algorithm, then substituting back up until you get something of the form $p_1a+p_2b=1$ where $p_1,p_2$ are polynomials and $b=x^7-1$. Since $x^7-1\equiv 0$ in your ring, you have $p_1a=1$ so $a^{-1}=p_1$. Not sure if someone here will be willing to work everything out by hand. We'll see. Just being realistic though.

Comment: A fairly simple algorithm (extended euclidean algorithm) tells you exactly what you need to do to solve the problem. To better understand the algorithm, start with simple integers as in [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/calculating-rsa-private-exponent-when-given-public-exponent-and-the-modulus-fact)

Comment: ok that's great, i just understand about using extended euclidean algorithm, i can find invers p1 (mod p2) if both p1 and p2 are polynomial, but if p1 is polynomial(a) and p2 integer(11) i can't figure it out.

Can anyone tell me how to divide polynomial a by integer 11?

Comment: @SuniaRaharja Take the coefficients (which are integers) modulo 11.

Comment: @SuniaRaharja typo alert: $4^X$ should be $4X$; do you the result of the multiplication as correct, using $X^7 \equiv 1, X^8 \equiv X$, etc? This we do in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ first, then reduce the coeffficients modulo $11$ (so $22 \equiv 0$, $-10 \equiv 1$).

Comment: Basically, using Extended Euclidean, do the inverse computation of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, doing the gcd with $X^7 - 1$, and reduce the coefficients modulo 11 afterwards.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma do you mean like this?;
gcd(x6 - 3x4 +2x2 + 3, X7 - 1), in this time(using Ext Euclid) i must find that;
x(x6 - 3x4 +2x2 + 3) + y(x7 - 1) = 1
so i can get the inverse is x, that's how it works right?

Comment: @SuniaRaharja yes, the polynomial $x$ (bad choice of notation) is indeed the inverse, and then you need to reduce mod 11. If all is well, you shouls get $a^{-1}$ or an equivalent (mod 11) polynomial.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma are you sure that if i'm doing it right i can get gcd(x6 - 3x4 +2x2 + 3, X7 - 1) is 1?, because im doing it now and i'm realize that's need alot of paper, and i'm doubt it that i can't get the answer

Comment: Pretty sure, if I have more time, I'll try to compute it too, by hand, of course.