# Factorizing N to derive D

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis

So I have the value of N. I have to use this value of N to find the value of D.

N = 265291078722948385089717069136983657793

Now I read about RSA algos and found out that

```
N=PQ | where P and Q are prime factors 

I found -
P - 14716976826788780483
Q - 18026193955816294571
```

2. The following is an example of what I've approached

   Choose p = 3 and q = 11
   Compute n = p * q = 3 * 11 = 33
   Compute φ(n) = (p - 1) * (q - 1) = 2 * 10 = 20
   Choose e such that 1 < e < φ(n) and e and n are coprime. Let e = 7
   Compute a value for d such that (d * e) % φ(n) = 1. One solution is d = 3 [(3 * 7) % 20 = 1]
3. We have

   P = 14716976826788780483
   Q = 18026193955816294571
   N = 265291078722948385089717069136983657793
   E = 65537 (given)
   φ(n) = 265291078722948385056973898354378582740    [using (p-1)(q-1)]

I'm unable to solve the equation  (d * e) % φ(n) = 1 for the above values.
We need to find/derive D.

I tried using this online calculator
[Princeton Extended Calc](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Edsri/modular-inversion.html)
But it doesn't accept large values

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm. This is the algorithm you should use to solve your problem. It is quite easy to implement in Python. Try it. You'll find your solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating RSA private exponent when given public exponent and the modulus factors using extended euclid](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/calculating-rsa-private-exponent-when-given-public-exponent-and-the-modulus-fact) (or possibly [How do we arrive to the equation for solving D in RSA?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/how-do-we-arrive-to-the-equation-for-solving-d-in-rsa))

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram alpha can do this:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=multiplicative+inverse+of+65537+mod+265291078722948385056973898354378582740

yields

d = 240894030773496778838526583320400223673

The alternative is to write a small C program using gmp or using python, e.g.

Comment: More than answer the question giving the number, I feel it would be better to explain the process and *how* to find the result. This would be useful for all other people having a similar problem with a different number.

Comment: The OP used an online calculator so I referred him to another one that does work

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." Generally, for homework questions like this pointers towards the correct way are much more useful than just handing over the result.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing code might help you, it should be this if I remember correctly. For large numbers you should use an NTL library.

```
/* 
   Recursive version of the euclidean algorithm, because it's much faster.
*/
void extendedEuclid(long a, long b, long& x, long& y)
{
        if (a%b== 0)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 1;
            return;
        }
        extendedEuclid(b,(a%b), x, y);
        long temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp - (y*(a//b));
}
/*
    Mudular inverse of a x = 1 mod m;
    returns x in this case.
*/
long modInverse(long a, long d)
{
    long x, y;
    extendedEuclid(a, d, x, y);
    if (!(x > zero()) && !(x ==0)) 
      x =(x+d);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: long is also not big enough. Use gmp or some other bignum library, if you want C. Of course Python will do this OK, as it has bignums built in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try with some Python code:

```
   def egcd(a, b):
        if a == 0:
            return (b, 0, 1)
        else:
            g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
            return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)


def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
    else:
        return x % m
```