# trying to get calculator and RSA calculatin does not make sense

Tags: rsa

got two question, I am novice in the area of crypto and currently in big learning curve.

From crypto book I am going over with, I see the RSA algorithm example as follows:

it chose two rand #-s:
p=47
q=71
n=pq=3337
and (p-1)(q-1) =3220
Now it chose e - encryption key as randomly for 79
but when it calculates the d the answers simply does not match:

From the book notation I understood the formula as:
d = 79^(-1) mod 3220 = 1019

So I am wondering is it really 79 to the power of minus 1? 79^(-1)
Then no matter what i do, I can not get 1019 as answer.

Second one, this is not directly related to cryptography but will ask here, I was trying to find a good android calculator to do a number crunching to checkout some of the crypto algorithms but so far did not find a decent one. I tried several of them from google store but all of them has some issue. Since i am doing algorithms related to crypto, looking for the one with MOD (%) and number E (exp(1)) but so far can not find one. I even found the virtual replica of good old TI 83+ and learned that one even has not have mod function (although it is possible to program the mod). So I thought may be one of you guys are using suitable calc?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse $\;$

Comment: I use RealCalc and of course the WolframAlpha app.

Comment: Why Android, you don't have a computer? (There is an Android port of PARI/GP, but I don't know how good it is.)

Comment: First part (the only one close to being on-topic) is addressed in [Calculating RSA private exponent](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/calculating-rsa-private-exponent-when-given-public-exponent-and-the-modulus-fact)