# Is there an easy way to calculate "d" in the RSA algorithm?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

Quite frankly, it is a pain to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to calculate d (the private exponent) in RSA. The equation used to find d is:

$$ e  d \equiv1~(\mathrm{mod}~ \varphi(n)).$$

Does anyone have a way to solve for d using basic algebra or something simpler? If not, can someone explain how to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find d?

Comment: if $\frac{1+k\cdot \varphi}{e}, k\in\mathbb N$ is an integral number, you have found $d$. This doesn't scale as nicely as the EEA does though.

Comment: On the other hand, $0 < k < e$, and so there are only $e-1$ possible values of $k$ to try; if $e$ is small, this would be practical (if less efficient than EE)

Comment: @SEJPM That's an answer, right? Or should I brush up on my RSA wrt "doesn't scale as nicely"? Connor C, $d$ is the private **exponent**. Together with the modulus it is the private key (although Chinese Remainder Theorem parameters could also be used).

Comment: Possible duplicate of *“[Calculating RSA private exponent when given public exponent and the modulus factors using extended euclid](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/calculating-rsa-private-exponent-when-given-public-exponent-and-the-modulus-fact)”*

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way which is widely known to calculate a modular inverse is finding the smallest $k\in\mathbb N$ such that the following expression is an integral integer:

$$\frac{1+k\cdot \varphi}{e}$$

If this is an integral integer, it is the inverse of $e$ modulo $\varphi$ and thus $d$ and you'll find it with at most $e$ tries.

---

The issue obviously know is that the run-time of this will grow linearly with the size of $e$, as opposed to the extended euclidean algorithm (EEA) which will run in time [proportional](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/258612/262906) to (a power of) the logarithm of $e$, which will especially be much faster than the above method when $e$ is chosen as large as the modulus. If you want to see examples and how-tos on the algorithm, [Wikipedia is your friend as usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).