# Find a LFSR given 2n (or more) non-consecutive keystream bits

Tags: cryptanalysis, lfsr

How can I calculate the polynomial and state of a LFSR given 2n (or more) non-consecutive keystream bits? It is known to be n bit. If they were consecutive, I could use the Berlekamp–Massey algorithm.

Simple example: n is 7 and I know the keystream is
0...0...1...0...1...0...1...1...1...0...1...0...1...0
where the . is an unknown bit

Any explanation or reference to paper or text book with algorithm will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if the question was related to a puzzle I'd created at the time: https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC7NE2Q_heroes-of-bp-5 :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given the sequence $b_i$ for $i$ multiple of $m>1$ with $0\le i<2n\,m$.

- If all the given $b_i$ are identical, we can't compute any missing $b_i$ (beyond a wild guess they are all $b_0$), stop.
- Build the sequence of $2n$ known bits $c_j=b_{(j\,m)}$ with $0\le j<2n$.
- Use Berlekamp–Massey to find a LFSR (polynomial $P$ of degree $k$ and $k$-bit initial state) matching $c_j$.
- Find some period $p$ of the $c_j$. For small degree $k$, we can simulate operation of the LFSR until the state repeats (OK to say $k\le40$ on a PC) or we can use [baby-step/giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) (OK to say $k\le75$ on a PC, see final section of this [former revision](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/59861/14)). But more generally, if $P$ factors into a product of [irreducible polynomials](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/59861/14) of degrees $k_r$ (thus with $k=\sum k_r$), then a period is $p=\prod(2^{k_r}-1)$.
  Note: For large polynomial, we can still efficiently compute $c_j$ for large arbitrary $j$ (see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60664/555)), once we have $P$ and starting state.
- If $\gcd(m,p)=1$, then $b_i$ also has period $p$, thus $\forall j\in\Bbb N,\ c_j=b_{(j\,m\bmod p)}$ ; it follows that $\forall i\in\Bbb N, b_i=c_{(i\,m^{-1}\bmod p)}$
  Note: $m^{-1}\bmod p$ needs to be computed only once, e.g. with the [half extended Euclidean algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54477/555).
  Note: with $p=\prod(2^{k_r}-1)$ and $m$ a power of two as in the question, $\gcd(m,p)=1$ always holds. If $\gcd(m,p)\ne1$, it might be possible to find a smaller period, by factoring $p$ and iteratively removing those factors that leave what remains a period, until finding the smallest period $p_\text{min}$ (which depends on the irreducible factors of $P$ being primitive or not, and on the starting point). $\gcd(m,p_\text{min})=1$ allows to conclude without guesswork.

Once $2k$ consecutive $b_j$ are found, an easy option to find the LFSR yielding them is to use Berlekamp–Massey again. The initial state of the LFSR for the $b_j$ (in Fibonacci form) is of course the first $k$ bits $b_i$.

<sup>Not covered (yet?): polynomial arithmetic would allow to directly derive the LFSR for the $b_j$ from the one for the $c_j$; and conclude when $\gcd(m,p_\text{min})\ne1$ and partial information on the $b_j$ is available.</sup>

Comment: Thank very much. I think I understand now. 
My initial example did not work as it failed in the gcd-step. I have changed it to one that is solvable.

Comment: how does one "efficiently compute c_j for large arbitrary j"?

Comment: @fgrieu - I'm confused.  In #1 for example, let j=9, the binary expression for J is b1001 or 2^3 + 2^0, then "step the generator 2^i for each i"?  Isn't that 9 steps?  What if j=2305843009213693952 (mod (2^64-1)).  To step the generator that many times would take years, wouldn't it?

Comment: @fgrieu - I have opened a new question on efficiently finding $c_j$ for large $j$  - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60634/lfsr-jump-ahead-algorithm

Comment: @fgrieu - what are the parameters to the baby-step-giant-step if I've computed a non-primitive P, order K in field GF($2^K$)?  Am i correct in assuming Alpha = P and Beta is $2^K$-1, with the goal of finding $x$ where $a^x = beta$ ?

Comment: @fgrieu - Please correct me if I am wrong.  In your above answer describing BSGS, $K$ is the $P$ obtained by BM algorithm (aka, $c_j$), the `generator` is $S_0$ of the LSFR, and the goal is to find $x$ such that $S_0^x mod P == S_0$,  $x > 0$.

Comment: @fgrieu - Please ignore my last comment, even I found it confusing upon re-reading it.  In your above answer describing BSGS, is $K$ the $P$ returned by BM algorithm?  Or is $K = 2^n-1$?

Comment: @fgrieu - Sorry, ignore the last one, too.  (K cannot be P obviously).  My coffee hasn't taken affect yet.  $K$ is the degree of P which is <= n.

Comment: @Les: Per the newly added math, your [example generator](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/60634/555) has period $(2^{14}-1)(2^{21}-1)(2^{29}-1)/127=145241018455818369$. For the factorization, you can [ask Wolfram's Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor+1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E11%2Bx%5E13%2Bx%5E16%2Bx%5E18%2Bx%5E20%2Bx%5E24%2Bx%5E25%2Bx%5E26%2Bx%5E27%2Bx%5E28%2Bx%5E29%2Bx%5E31%2Bx%5E33%2Bx%5E34%2Bx%5E35%2Bx%5E36%2Bx%5E37%2Bx%5E40%2Bx%5E41%2Bx%5E44%2Bx%5E46%2Bx%5E47%2Bx%5E50%2Bx%5E51%2Bx%5E52%2Bx%5E54%2Bx%5E55%2Bx%5E56%2Bx%5E57%2Bx%5E60%2Bx%5E63%2Bx%5E64+modulo+2).

Comment: @fgrieu - thank you, that works.  However, I ran my polynomial through Wolfram's Alpha and got 3 polynomials of degrees 14, 21, and 29 which line up with your k term in your factors, only when I read your answer, I would have come up with $(2^15-1)(2^22-1)(2^30-1), where my k values are the degrees of the 3 polynomials.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Les: to get the shortest period, we take the period $\prod(2^{k_j}-1)$ where $k_j$ is the degree of irreducible polynomial factors, and pull out its (integer) factors while what remains is a period. Among reasons that is necessary: some of the irreducible polynomial factors might not be primitive; or/and said factors could divide the starting point (in Galois form); and I'm leaving aside what happens when an irreducible factor is squared. I know how to get the right result, but I'm less than fully comfortable with the subject, and asked [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2850476/35016).

Comment: @fgrieu - This is very helpful, the period is correct.  Additionally, I found by experimentation (for my purposes) that the period need not be the shortest.  I tried several multiples of the shortest period and all of them also worked.  The missing link for me is that Wolfram's Alpha gave me $(1+x+x^3+x^4+x^9+x^10+x^11+x^12+x^14) (1+x^2+x^6+x^7+x^12+x^13+x^15+x^16+x^18+x^19+x^21) (1+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^8+x^9+x^12+x^13+x^15+x^17+x^18+x^19+x^22+x^23+x^25+x^28+x^29)$ and the formula above tell me take $\displaystyle\prod(2^{k_r}-1)$ where $k_r$ is the *degree* (your comment uses the *order*).

Comment: In other words, if I were to repeat this experiment on a different cipher and Wolfram's Alpha gave me similar factors with orders like say 12, 23, 29 (these are just made up), I would take their degrees and get $(2^13-1)(2^24-1)(2^30-1)$, and I would be wrong.  Or, I could take the *order* of each instead (but then I would be guessing, I prefer not to guess).  Is Wolfram's just adding the degree to each factor (similar to how $x^64$ is implicitly added to the characteristic polynomial)?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about the Latex errors, I am still learning it.

Comment: Embarrassing, I think I have my understanding of "order" and "degree" reversed.