# Finding Multiplicative Inverse In Field

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, finite-field, algebraic-attack

Consider the finite set Z_257 of non-negative integers less than 257. The number 257 is a prime, so Z_257 forms a field with addition and multiplication mod 257. How can I use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse of the element 254 in this field.

Answer (score 2):

For such small numbers, brute force search will do: by definition $a^{-1}\bmod p$ is the integer $x$ in $[0,p)$ with $a\,x\bmod p=1$. The desired $x$ can be found by trial and error. This requires less than $p$ additions, tests, and subtractions, noting we can move from one candidate $x$ to the next using that $((a\,(x+1))\bmod p)\,=\,((((a\,x)\bmod p)+x)\bmod p)$.

---

One of the most recommendable and fastest classical algorithms is the (half) [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures). In crypto, we sometime prefer that [variant avoiding negatives](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54477/555). There also are [binary variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Extensions). Essentially, these find unknown $x$ solving the [Bézout identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) $a\,x+p\,y=1$ for given $a$ and $p$, and some immaterial unknown $y$.

---

Yet another method uses $x\gets a^{p-2}\bmod p$. It's applicable when $p$ is prime and integer $a$ is not a multiple of $p$. It follows from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). This uses less than $2\log_2(p)$ modular multiplications, using [binary modular expoentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Left-to-right_binary_method). The method is extensible to any group of known [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)).

Comment: Using brute force as suggested, with 254x ≡ 1 (mod 257) I arrived at 171. Is this correct?

Comment: 254×171 = 257×169 + 1, thus the result is OK, congratulations. But I advise trying one of the extended Euclidean algorithms; it's much faster.