# Completing RSA Encryption

Tags: encryption, rsa, decryption

Being new to cryptology, I'm trying to understand how I would complete RSA encryption by hand.
I can only follow the formula so far before becoming very confused.

I want to encrypt the value "123"

First, I am to select 2 primes. I choose:
$$p = 101\\
q = 103$$

Next, I compute: $$n = p\cdot q = 10403$$.

After that, I compute: $$\varphi(n) = (p-1)\cdot(q-1) = 10200$$

Now, I want to choose a public exponent, and I choose 3 for this.

I believe the formula to use is:
$$d = e^{−1}\bmod\varphi(n)$$

I don't understand how to plug this formula in, nor do I know how I would encrypt "123" using this formula. Also, I don't know how I would find the decryption exponent either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: e (and also d, but you don't choose that) must be co-prime to p-1 and q-1. Your q-1 is 102 and 3 is not co-prime to 102. If you wanted actual security, which is impossible with a tiny toy size like this, choosing p and q adjacent or near is defective. d can be computed as e inverse mod _either_ phi(n) (Euler) _or_ lambda(n) (Carmichael). All of the above are covered by wikipedia, and by many many many existing Qs.

Comment: As stated above, your choice of $e$ is incompatible with your choice of $q$. For the computation of $d$, see the (half-)[extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures) or [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5889/555). Textbook RSA encryption is per $m\to c=m^e\bmod n$. Decryption is per $c\to m=c^d\bmod n$. These computations are [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Comment: In practice p and q should not be too close, because this makes factorization of n easy. (Just telling, because you choose p and q close together)

Answer (score 1):

Fgrieu essentially gave the answer in comment, I will try to elaborate a bit in answer form.

You can use extended euclidean algorithm to find d from e, but note the e you selected will not work. Because e is not co-prime with $\varphi(n)$ You need to select another one. For efficiency we usually like to select a small e with few set bits, usually of the form $2^k+1$ since 3 doesn't work you can try others.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm
Here is an online calculator: https://planetcalc.com/3298/

It will not only give you the gcd (which needs to be 1) it will also give you a,b so that:
$a*e + b*\varphi(n) = 1$ which essentially means $a*e = 1 mod \varphi(n)$ which is what we wanted.

You then encrypt by calculating $c = m^e\space mod(n)$ and decrypt using $m = c^d\space mod(n)$
Both done via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation